# Quadcopter Flat Surface Roll Pitch angle not 0 Degree

Tags: quadcopter, pid

At 11:13 or 2:22 [of this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wrkiylHe3QY) or 0:09 [of this second video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=j0JF97Y7aH4) the drone itself is on flat surface but the flight controller itself must have been placed in tilted position (not intentionally) on frame a little so the Pitch and Roll angles are not perfectly 0 degrees. When the PID makes corrections to make FC  at 0 degree level for hovering over, the drone itself will be tilted so the drone will go in x or y direction. Should we mount FC with this manner to the drone's frame (in a way we read exactly 0 degrees) or are we making correction to these things during flyting with remote controller to make it stable.

Or is there a code trick in flight controller like taking the start angles as flat degrees so -2 for example is flat level for it.

I hope i am clear. Any help is appriciated.

Answer (score 2):

As demonstrated in your second video you can give the FC an angle offset (it does not have to be a multiple op 90°). In order to find the appropriate offset you can place the quadcopter on a level surface use the angles you measure then as offset.

It is also possible to make a controller which controls the x and y position or velocity of the quadcopter using the pitch and roll as outputs (this is also known as consecutive loop closing). By using a PID controller for this then the integral action can also counteract the offset of the FC orientation.

Comment: Thanks for answer. So if we do not make correction on FC angles the quadcopter wont hover over stable on air and we need to make more effort with remote controller. Is this correct ?

Comment: @ssdflash01 Yes, if the FC is tilted with respect to (the thrust vector of) the quadcopter then when trying to hover by controlling the pitch and roll angles to zero the quadcopter will accelerate in one direction (until air friction forces it to a constant velocity).

Comment: Thank you one last question :). Do you know anything about how fc handles with it intenally. I mean does it automatically takes those offseted angles as flat points and make corrections to each new angle reading. Like pitch angle -1 in flat surface so it subtracts -1 from each pitch angles.

Comment: @ssdflash01 I do not know for sure, but it is probably is just an offset added through software.